# Error: Cannot find module './internal/re'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-package

PS C:\Users\QHTF\Desktop\Statistics> npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/re'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js
- C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js:2:20)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js',
  'C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js',
  'C:\Users\QHTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
  ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install modules according to your node project. It should be very convenient if you use any control panel. You can install it from Module(s)>Manage section.